# Filter by close reason in the 10k Tools

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, 10k-tools

Sometimes I browse closed questions (older than 2 days) and vote to delete them, but I don't want to delete duplicates, because they serve their purpose as placeholders for searches.

There's no way to see the close reason from the Close tab in the 10k tools, can I ask for a label to be added specifying the reason, or a way to filter those questions out?

Comment: Which 10k tool are you using?  I use the "Recently Closed Posts" tool because it has the close reason below the title. http://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-closed  It *would* be nice to be able to filter them though.

Comment: @Bill, I use the closed tab (http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=close&daterange=last7days) which is easier to read than the recently closed list, without scrolling (on meta though, but it's the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was amended a while ago, but the 10k tools `close` tab now groups together questions by the close reasons, for both accumulating close votes and those trying to get reopened.